# How to write custom SMT in Kafka Source Connector to obfuscate private data

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

Suppose that I want to set up a Kafka source connector to pump some data from my DB into my Kafka. Now, suppose that due to security reasons I want to obfuscate (say, apply a hash function) to some of the columns in my DB. Is there a standard way to to that with Kafka Connect, or do I have to first create private topics and then write some custom code to create public versions of those topics (with hashed values for sensitive data)?

I know that there's such thing as transformations ([MaskField](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/transforms/maskfield.html?_ga=2.26017726.2076448550.1602063198-1842461068.1602063198#maskfield), etc.), but none of them seems to solve my problem. For example, MaskField does something like +1-234-567-8987 -> "***-***-****", which I do not want to happen, because I still want to have distinct entries for different input values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kafka Connect makes it very convenient to write your own single message transformation (SMT). If none of the default transformations serve your purpose you can build a custom transformator.

This [blog](https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-connect-single-message-transformation-tutorial-with-examples/#how-to-write-a-smt) explains how to build your own, together with a full example provided on [GitHub](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-insert-uuid):

You need to implement `Transformation<R>` and override the `apply()` method with your custom algorithm to handle personal related data.

When you compile that code as a JAR and make it available to Kafka Connect via the `plugin.path` specified in the Connect worker’s properties file, then the transforms can be configured in the connector properties.