# Make A custom transform for kafka cdc and Debezium

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium, change-data-capture

I'm trying to create a custom transform for Kafka CDC.I want running a replication between MySQL and MongoDB. I prefer when a row update/insert in MySQL database the records the related to that row (A hierarchy tree structure) corresponding complex JSON document(a hierarchy JSON document) update/insert in MongoDB. Can I implement custom transform for Debezium?

Comment: You may refer to the following two questions. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57604283/write-a-custom-kafka-connect-single-message-transform https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64250997/how-to-write-custom-smt-in-kafka-source-connector-to-obfuscate-private-data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A custom transform for Debezium is no different from a custom SMT for Connect framework, ignoring the defined scehma of the Debezium event.

1. Create a Java project with a dependency on at least `org.apache.kafka: connect-transforms`
2. Implement the [`Transformation`](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/javadocs/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/connect/transforms/Transformation.html) interface.

   - Ideally, add unit tests for this as well
   - You can look into the Kafka source code for how existing ones are implemented.
3. Package it as a JAR. If it needs external dependencies, a shaded JAR will work as long as you relocate any packages that Kafka itself will have on its classpath. For any of those, you should ensure `provided` scope; for example, `kafka-clients` or `jackson`-related libraries.
4. Copy the JAR into a directory listed on the `plugin.path` of the connect worker(s) configs.

https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/transforms/custom.html